# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord Conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

We're trying to establish best practices for a project and we're discussing where SQL and ActiveRecord methods should be placed.

My understanding is that you want to keep as much logic out of controller as possible. I think we agree on complex SQL queries belonging to models, but we are disagreeing on where simple AR methods should live, whether in the controller or in the model.

So with something simplistic like:

```
client = Client.find(10)
```

Would it ideally live in a model or controller? I understand that it may not make much/any difference, and the answer will be doesn't matter, but any insight into the question would be great.

Comment: `client = Client.find(10)` is a fairly simple operation and a bit out of context, so I'd say it might go into the controller or the model depending upon why it's being done. With no other guidance, I might say controller. The convention is for the controller and views to be light on code, and the code being in models (and view helping code in the helpers) but it is a *convention* (not an absolute rule) which is there for a reason, which is that a lot of code is related to sorting, sifting, and processing data, which is model-related. The controller can have *some* code. :)

Comment: It was a discussion that stemmed from reading this from a blog: "Sophisticated queries (i.e., that are more complex than a simple find); generally speaking, you should never use the where method, or any other query-building methods like it, outside of the model class itself".

Which I just now realize he is saying finds are okay to use in controller, so what about a Client.where("first_name='Carly'")

I assume that would be meant to be outside of controller?

Comment: For `Client.where("first_name='Carly'")`, I would still say *it depends* (on context). :)

Comment: Can you make general assertions as to when it would stay in controller and when it would be abstracted out to a model?

Comment: I was thinking if it's in the context of providing a commonly used data filter, it would be model. If it's being used as a selector based upon a user action to direct what happens in a view, then controller. The controller is the traffic cop (I never really liked that metaphor, but it works here I guess).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the insight. I think we've gleaned enough here to make better decisions moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one good answer to this and I have a feeling this may well get closed because of that, but here goes anyway.

`Client.find(10)` and `Client.where("first_name='Carly'")` are about as simple of a query as you can make.  You simply can't replace the first with a model method.  The second I suppose you could make a `search` method, but that could well be premature.

I think the point of those articles is that you don't want something like this in your controller:

`Client.where("created_at > X").where("some_flag = true").order('created_at DESC')`

That is a pretty clear candidate for a named scope (or a couple of them).

That said there are times I will leave that in my controller because it incredibly specific to that controller and won't be used anywhere else (ever) so there's not a lot of point in DRYing it up IMHO.

However, most times when you start doing that you'll realize there are some common functionality that you can extract into your model so you can use it elsewhere.

Comment: I think this is the core of what we were looking for. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

Except for class [`scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html)s, you could also consider having **finders** models, which extracts queries from both models and controllers.

Take a look at how [Gitlab handles it](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/app/finders).

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I haven't heard of finders models before. That's an interesting concept, I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I really think that the "core" principles here are DRY and KISS.

If you have a relatively lengthy query (several `where` clauses, `join`s, etc) that is required by several of your controllers, extract it as a scope.

If you have a fairly lengthy query that seemingly overwhelmes the entire controller method, you should probably extract it as a scope.

Comment: Thanks art. I think it's become clearer how we should handle simple versus not-simple ActiveRecord methods and abstracting out the scope.